# Adding parsed JSON to a ListView and displaying it

Tags: android, json, listview

```
public class GithubTab extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView repoListView;

    private ListAdapter adapter;
    private List<RepositoryItem> repoListItems;

    private List<String> repoNameList;
    private List<String> userNameList;
    private List<String> descriptionList;

    private TextView tvData;

    private static final String TAG = "Github Tab";

    Button buttonHit;
    TextView resultText;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.github_tab, container, false);

        repoListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.repoList);

        repoListItems = new ArrayList<>();
        repoNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        userNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        descriptionList = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new ListAdapter(getContext(), repoListItems);
        repoListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        tvData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvJsonItem);

        // Clickable: able to open the GitHub webpage of the re

        repoListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Clicked id" + view.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        new JSONTask().execute("https://api.github.com/users/whyjay17/repos");

        for(int i = 0; i < repoNameList.size(); i++) {
            repoListItems.add(new RepositoryItem(i, repoNameList.get(i), userNameList.get(i), "ddd"));
        }

        return view;

    }

    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override

        // Any non-UI thread process is running in this method. After completion, it sends the result to OnPostExecute
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {

                .... Code Hidden ....

                return retreivedJson;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                //cant close null

                if (connection != null) {
                    // close both connection and the reader
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;

        }


        public void formatJSONArray(String results){
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(results);
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(jsonObject.optString("name") != null) {
                        //tvData.append(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        repoNameList.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));

                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "1 " + repoNameList.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    if(jsonObject.optJSONObject("owner") != null){
                        JSONObject ownerObject=jsonObject.getJSONObject("owner");

                        if(ownerObject.optString("login")!=null) {
                            //tvData.append(ownerObject.getString("login"));
                            userNameList.add(ownerObject.getString("login"));
                            //ownerObject.append(ownerObject.getString("avatar_url"));
                        }
                    }
                }


            }catch (JSONException jsonException){

            }
        }

        /*
        * Called after the background computation finishes. Result of doInBackground is passed in as a parameter.
        *
        * */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

       /* for JSONArray data*/
            if(result!=null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                formatJSONArray(result);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The code above basically tries to parse a JSON data from https://api.github.com/users/famous/repos, adds some certain info (repo name, id, description) to the corresponding lists, and tries to display that on the listView that I created.

The listView works when I hard code the information (meaning that there is no problem with the listView itself), but when I try to put in the data inside the list (which has the parsed JSON info and I tested that it is actually inside the list), it gives me an empty list.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` for your adapter after add new elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data come **asynchronous** so inside `onCreateView()` the list data may not be ready yet for adding to adapter.

You need to move the code that add elements to ListView adapter into `onPostExecute()`, after `formatJSONArray()` method, then call `notifyDatasetChange()` to invalidate the ListView

```
@Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);

            /* for JSONArray data*/
            if(result!=null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                formatJSONArray(result);
                for(int i = 0; i < repoNameList.size(); i++) {
                    repoListItems.add(new RepositoryItem(i, 
                    repoNameList.get(i), userNameList.get(i), "ddd"));
                }

                adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
           }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < repoNameList.size(); i++) {
     repoListItems.add(new RepositoryItem(i,repoNameList.get(i),userNameList.get(i), "ddd"));
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

`
add this line before

```
}catch (JSONException jsonException){
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call adapter.notifiDatasetchange() in your **formatJSONArray** method:

```
public void formatJSONArray(String results){
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(results);
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if(jsonObject.optString("name") != null) {
                    //tvData.append(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    repoNameList.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));

                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "1 " + repoNameList.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if(jsonObject.optJSONObject("owner") != null){
                    JSONObject ownerObject=jsonObject.getJSONObject("owner");

                    if(ownerObject.optString("login")!=null) {
                        //tvData.append(ownerObject.getString("login"));
                        userNameList.add(ownerObject.getString("login"));
                        //ownerObject.append(ownerObject.getString("avatar_url"));
                    }
                }
            }
        adapter.notifiDatasetchange();

        }catch (JSONException jsonException){

        }
    }
```

If it don't work , you can set adapter again in your **formatJSONArray** method

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(getContext(), repoListItems);
repoListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

It worked for me. I hope it can help your problem!